# Change the color of google marker based on the selection made in the html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have a html table which consist of list of location information and its location is shown in a google map with a marker. Now when I click on the change button in that given table row, the related marker color is to be changed. I have tried following code, but it is changing only 1 marker color.

```js
var beaches = [
  ["Haringhata", 21.984606, 89.974250],
  ["West Bengal, India",
    21.681855, 88.584980
  ]
];
var markers = [];
var map;


function changeColor(clickEvent) {
  this.marker_point.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
}

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[0][1], beaches[0][2]),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };

  for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    this.marker_point = marker;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(beaches[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
    markers.push(marker);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


$(function() {
  $('.deleteMarker').on('click', function(e) {
    var dataId = $(this).closest('td')[0].dataset.id;
    changeColor(dataId);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<table id="sum_table">
  <tr class="titlerow">
    <th>S.N.</th>
    <th>Community</th>
    <th width="18%">Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Haringhata</td>
    <td data-id="0"><button class="deleteMarker">Change</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>West Bengal, India</td>
    <td data-id="1"><button class="deleteMarker">Change</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
function changeColor(clickEvent) {
  this.marker_point.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
}
```

should be:

```
function changeColor(clickEvent) {
  markers[clickEvent].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
}
```

`this` in that event listener refers to the `window` object, there is only ever one `window.marker_point` (the last one set in your loop).  Click event is the data-id from the HTML, use it to reference the correct marker from the `markers` array.

This is the same issue that is addressed in the infowindow listener function closure in the question [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example), and is a common problem with asynchronous function variables in loops.

```js
var beaches = [
  ["Haringhata", 21.984606, 89.974250],
  ["West Bengal, India",
    21.681855, 88.584980
  ]
];
var markers = [];
var map;


function changeColor(clickEvent) {
  markers[clickEvent].setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
}

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[0][1], beaches[0][2]),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };

  for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    this.marker_point = marker;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(beaches[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
    markers.push(marker);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


$(function() {
  $('.deleteMarker').on('click', function(e) {
    var dataId = $(this).closest('td')[0].dataset.id;
    changeColor(dataId);
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<table id="sum_table">
  <tr class="titlerow">
    <th>S.N.</th>
    <th>Community</th>
    <th width="18%">Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Haringhata</td>
    <td data-id="0"><button class="deleteMarker">Change</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>West Bengal, India</td>
    <td data-id="1"><button class="deleteMarker">Change</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="map"></div>
```